# Finding string in file with batch and call other batch

Tags: batch-file

I am on a need to finde if an output log ends with a desired string, and call another batch if it does.

I have already tried some solutions at StackOverflow but it is still not working.

```
title Validate daily execution


findstr /C: "Exiting with code 0" .\logs\20171116.log
if %errorlevel%==0 (
BBBB
CALL  AutoLogEmail
) else (
AAAAAAAa

)
```

And the file that I am looking for in a sub folder, with the name above has the values

> 16-11-2017  6:50:00,75 START PROCESS XXXXXXX.ISPAC Microsoft (R) SQL
>   Server Execute Package Utility Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:  06:50:00 DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_SUCCESS (0). Started:  06:50:00 Finished: 06:52:03 Elapsed: 
>   122.929 seconds 16-11-2017  6:52:04,00 END PROCESS XXXXXXXX.ISPAC : Exiting with code 0

Is there any especific function that I shall use? Can someone point me the error and explain why it is not working?

Thanks in advance
Helder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <kbd>Space</kbd> between `/c:` and the string in your `findstr` command is your problem.

With that <kbd>Space</kbd> in the place indicated, `findstr` will generate a syntax-error message and set `errorlevel` to `2`.

Remove it and `findstr` will attempt to find the string in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
@echo off
title Validate daily execution

>nul find "Exiting with code 0" .\logs\20171116.log && (
    CALL  AutoLogEmail
) || (
    echo not found
    pause
)
```

In this case, it depends on the find command, which whill cause the && operator (which only executes the command after it if the previous one doesn't fail) to either call autologmail, or echo not found if it didn't find anything.